# how to deserializeuntype list<object>?

Tags: apex, json, deserialize, jsongenerator

I have below JSON, that we are getting from external system and I am trying to use `json.deserializeUntype` to associate  it to respective maps, objects etc. And then trying to insert into respective parent and child SObjects of Salesforce. Everything goes fine until I encounter `element_types` list , since I am getting list of objects(List) , I am unable to cast it to map of string ,object and receive an invalid conversion at run-time list any to map string,any... My objective is also convert these list of object `element_types` and then receive them as key, pairs to go on further?  It fails when taking object o into `ele2`, claiming run-time exception converting `List<ANY>` to `MAp<String,ANY>` which I understand and need a way to have convert to map? I have also tried iterating through object, but cannot get the key value pairs of object?

```
{
 @HttpPost
    global static void createElements() 
    {
        Map<String, Object> results = new Map<String, Object>();
        Map<String, Object> elementsMap = new Map<String, Object>();

        String TemplateVerName;
        String TemplateVerUUID;
        INFF__Template_Version__c TempVerID;

        try
        {
            results=RestIFF_Helper.getRequestBody();
            TemplateVerName=(String)results.get('name');
            TemplateVerUUID=(String)results.get('uuid');
            system.debug('request from form builder is  ' + results );

            TempVerID=BaseIFF_TempVersion.getTempVer(TemplateVerUUID);

            system.debug('temp ver id is ' +TempVerID.Id );
            system.debug('temp  id is ' +TempVerID.INFF__Template__r.Id);



            //List<object> elements = new List<object>();
            List<object> elementsData = (List<Object>)results.get('elements');
                        List<object> elementsTypes = new List<Object>();





            system.debug('template name is ' + TemplateVerName);
            system.debug('template UUID is ' + TemplateVerUUID);
            system.debug('elements to be inserted are ' + elementsData);
            List<INFF__Standard_Element__c> stdElementToInsert = new List<INFF__Standard_Element__c>();
            List<INFF__Standard_Element__c> stdElementToUpdate = new List<INFF__Standard_Element__c>();
            List<INFF__Standard_Element_Type__c> ElementTypesToInsert = new List<INFF__Standard_Element_Type__c>();

            Map<String,Object> ele=new Map<String,Object>();

            Map<String,Object> ele1;
                        Map<String,Object> ele2;

                        Map<String,Object> elementTypeMap=new Map<String,List<Object>>();

            Map<String,String> UUIDChildParent = new Map<String,String>();
            Map<String,Id> UUIDStdElementIdMap = new  Map<String,Id>();

            for(object o : elementsData){

                ele = (Map<String,Object>)o;
                elementTypeMap.put((String)ele.get('uuid'),ele.get('element_types'));
                UUIDChildParent.put((String)ele.get('uuid'),(String)ele.get('parent_uuid'));

                INFF__Standard_Element__c se= new INFF__Standard_Element__c(name=(String)ele.get('name'),
                                      UUID__c=(String)ele.get('uuid'),Template_Version__c=TempVerID.Id,
                                                                            Order__c=(Decimal)ele.get('order')
                                                                           );
                stdElementToInsert.add(se);
            }

            system.debug('element types with ucid of respective element ' + elementTypeMap);

            for(String o : elementTypeMap.keyset()){


                         ele2=(Map<STring,object>)elementTypeMap.get(o);



            }




            if(!results.isEmpty())
                RestIFF_Helper.setResponse('Elements Created ,successfully passed data into salesforce',200);


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Log and handle any exceptions

        }        

    }
}
```

Comment: You can try to use ```instanceof``` to determine type of the object

Comment: @kurunve issue is not with respect to  casting it to right type but "how to" get key value pair of the list object as similar to that of map

Comment: Can you also provide the sample JSON??

Comment: Can you update your code to actually include the line where you deserialize?